# Default init.vim file

Tags: neovim

For nvim, can anyone show me what the default init.vim file look like? I had to make my own and I don't know what they look like by default

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 2):

There's no default init file in neovim. There's no requirement to create one.

If you have such file then it should consist of the same commands you (can) input at (neo)vim command prompt.

If you still don't know what you can do with Vim you should learn this, not "how do I setup the tool I can't make use of". The recommended reading for beginners is built-in tutor and the main help page.

If you already do know something but need some specific directions about init file I recommend Romain's page at github: https://github.com/romainl/idiomatic-vimrc